# Little search for the bored: Find the hidden word

Tags: word, word-property, poetry

> My lovely poem:
>
> To won my feisty price
> You have to ztop the pies
> We don't wont urban mice
> We wamt the lumb life, guys!

A secret word is hidden in the poem. What is it?

Hint:

> Look behind you, a three-headed monkey!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My attempt:

> We need to correct the spelling mistakes in the poem as follows:
>
> To w**I**n my feisty price
>  You have to **S**top the **L**ies
>  We don't w**A**nt urban mice
>  We wa**N**t the **D**umb life, guys!
>
> So the hidden word is **ISLAND**.  This fits with the hint, which is a quote from the *Monkey Island* series of video games.

Comment: Congrats, I missed quite a few of the letters in my botched attempt

Comment: Surely "price" is also incorrect?

Comment: I have to think that price is supposed to be prize but OP made a spelling mistake